# Correct Authentication Pattern using Passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

It seems the [Passport docs](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/) suggest using a pattern such as:

```
app.get("/my/protected/resource", passport.authenticate("local"), function(req, res){
    res.json({my:"protected resource"});
});
```

as the standard way to protect resources after authentication. However, as I have tried this strategy repeatedly, it has repeatedly given me `401 - Unauthorized`. Rather, a middleware solution such as the following worked:

```
exports.loggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Checking credentials...');
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
    }
};
```

This, however, is either not found, or is not made prominent in the docs. Which of these two are the standard and correct way of protecting resources using passport.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sessions, I generally use this type of pattern:

```
app.get('/resource', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'
}))
```

as shown http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

If you want the response in the same function:

```
app.get('/resource', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'
}), function(req, res){
    res.json({my:"protected resource"});
})
```

Comment: Okay - so if it's an API (like I'm building) then most likely the successRedirect wouldn't happen, it would most likely be a JSON object returned instead. But if it was a website, say, and I was trying to access "/dashboard", would the successRedirect have to be "/dashboard", too? Or would that create an infinite loop of some sort? How do I push them straight through to the page they requested?

Comment: On an API, I'd go for the second approach if its as short as `res.json`.  Basically `successRedirect` allows you to separate your code into a more digestable function so the authentication process is separate from your main application (ie. a website where you have a login page and many protected pages).  Based on sessions, once you login (say at `/login/`) then the positive authentication will be stored so that if you `successRedirect` to `/protectedpage` it will remember it.  On those other pages, you should check if the user is authenticated by reading `req.user`

Comment: So, for that last part of your comment (the req.user check), are you saying basically the middleware "loggedIn" that I posted originally should just be modified to check for req.user and then next()'ed? This is where I'm confused! If I want to protect resource foo and bar, do I use passport.authenticate() or check for req.user!?

Comment: Check for `req.user` (which will be empty if not logged in).  If that is the case, then send them to a `/login` page.  If it's for an API though, you may be wanting to `passport.authenticate` every time since you might want every API call to be authenticated without session handling (saves your server memory if you have a lot of API clients)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be redirected to "/" (as your second example does) rather than getting a 401 (the default behavior) when trying to access a protected resource unauthenticated, using `passport.authenticate`, you can use the redirect options, as specified in the second section of the page in the docs that you linked:

```
app.get("/my/protected/resource",
  passport.authenticate("local", {failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res){

  res.json({my:"protected resource"});
});
```